# Angular JS serializing forms on action

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I have multiple forms which are generated automatically and each form may contain a number of checkboxes which just have different ID's - they represent objects in the database.

I want to serialize this form to perform actions such as sending messages, generating scripts for selected elements.

How do I do that :)?

```
<form action="{% verbatim %}{{item.assign_url}}{% endverbatim %}" id="form">
    <input name="submissiongroup" type="checkbox" value="{{subItem.id}}" />

        <a ng-click="getReport()" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-file"></i> Pobierz raport</a>
        <a ng-click="closeTask()" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-times"></i> Zakończ zgłoszenie</a>
        <a ng-click="sendSMS()" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i> Wyślij SMS</a>
        <a ng-click="assignSubmission(subItem.id)" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-star"></i> Przypisz do mnie</a>

</form>
```

My js file:

```
    module.controller("SubmissionTreeController", function($scope, $http) {
    var update_dashboard = function() {
        $http.get('/test/submission/active/ajax/').success(function(data) {
            $scope.list = data.results;
        });
    };

    update_dashboard();

    // var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // $scope.$apply(update_dashboard);
    // }, 1000 * 30);

    $scope.toggle = function(scope) {
        scope.toggle();
    };

    $scope.assignSubmission = function(data) {
        var url = Django.url('submission:assign', {
            site : site,
            pk: data
        });


        $http.post(url, I_SHOULD_PASS_DATA_HERE).success(function(data) {
            console.log('win!');
        });
    };

    $scope.sendSMS = function(scope) {

    };

    $scope.getReport = function(scope) {

    };

    $scope.closeTask = function(scope) {

    };

});
```

Edit 1:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="submissiongroup" ng-change="selectCheckbox(subItem.id)" ng-model="subItem.id"/>

$scope.selectCheckbox = function(scope) {
    console.log($scope.subItem);
};
```

Comment: By default, form data is sent as JSON, which is a already serialized. Is there something different you're after?

Comment: So how do I bind my buttons like <a ng-click="getReport()"> to form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form data object (subItem) to collect the form fields data. For example, there are one checkbox 'submissiongroup' and one hidden field 'submissiongroupname' whithin the form. You can use the ng-model directive to bind the input value with model data. Then use [jquery $.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) function to serialize the form data object and pass it to the second parameter of the $http.post function.

**Note:** You don't have to set the "action" attribute of the form element in this case. Angular will prevent the default action of form submit (submit the form data to server by reloading the full page) unless the form element has an action attribute specified.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form id="form">
      <input name="submissiongroup" type="checkbox" ng-model="subItem.id" />
      <input name="submissiongroupname" type="hidden" ng-model="subItem.name" />
      <a ng-click="getReport()" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-file"></i> Pobierz raport</a>
      <a ng-click="closeTask()" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-times"></i> Zakończ zgłoszenie</a>
      <a ng-click="sendSMS()" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-envelope"></i> Wyślij SMS</a>
      <a ng-click="assignSubmission(subItem.id)" class="action-button"><i class="icon icon-star"></i> Przypisz do mnie</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var module = angular.module("MyApp",[])
module.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope, $http){
  //fake data
  $scope.subItem = {id:1, name:"group1"};

  //methods
  $scope.getReport = function(){

  }

  $scope.closeTask = function(){

  }

  $scope.sendSMS = function(){

  }

  $scope.assignSubmission = function(id){
    var url = Django.url('submission:assign', {
        site : site,
        pk: data
    });
    $http.post(url,$.param($scope.subItem))
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log('win!');
    });
  }
});
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. When I select one or multiple checkboxes then $scope.subItem is still empty. It should somehow get updated. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you use the ng-model directive? What value did you assign to it?

Comment: Check my edited message called edit 1. I did use subItem.id for ng-model. I've created empty scope object and selected some checkboxes and triggered the event assignSubmission.

Comment: Any error in the console? What's the output of the function selectCheckbox() executing?

Comment: So far this function is empty, it does nothing - the goal of this function is to select children of element when item is selected.

Comment: what's the output of console.log($scope.subItem)?

Comment: It returns: Object {}

Comment: I don't see any ng-controller in your HTML. Did you attach the ng-controller="SubmissionTreeController" to the ancestor DOM node of the form element? I wrote a [simple runnable example](http://jsfiddle.net/3vyUA/1/). You could refer to it.

Comment: Yeah, I got it sorted out. I'll post that code tomorrow